# Can't connect to my app with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

On rails 4, I am using devise to authenticate my users and I am also adding a facebook authentication...
I've followed this[documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) and I set up in my config var on heroku.

```
 config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", callback_url: "CALLBACK_URL"
```

Now when I am on my url if I click on **sign up with facebook link** I arrive on facebook login page (as I am logged out from facebook) and when I clcik login I am redirected to this:
What is wrong? 
Thanks for your help :)

[image]

here are my logs

```
at=info method=GET path="/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBSQ125f8npBttjqtAZ4uN9M2-u_DaHqMdp2LJadvBUESXOP_u7q-OL_U0XDlrk836GuXu63OPXAerDTsG7xwgXSg93VgSEMxjs-L733DCsQ1zpoPBMxUgGIQLFb3QxQIqU544ymZuNsDEhdofUj58hrcjOOpg9fEZjQb3lvZqCd34mPt2MVPjQJJAMoe1Vo5n0Y1ozyhYjpSH2DfKTHsmK38ba_7TD8I48M47g0rItI55vvLkrogHLnpgf_NlHjgeHMXldPzsKgEybRM2ouR8S6zKNLsWRJlQ_TbJe_sYuRU85WNoJeAlRrHW-iiw1N4XHIxO2W-JTMG71jwqelSjrPM6c1kPzJbNu-zxjo1vNpQ&state=8a8f36fdd32be2f5931f05ac9176c6f5f5412ef9a8f84eeb" host=duclostutos.herokuapp.com request_id=7968a919-2170-4030-8a32-87d64299e5bf fwd="92.171.113.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=939ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

I could have a problem with my routes....

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    get "/best_voted", to: "tutos#best_voted"
    resources :tutos
    namespace :users do
      resources :tutos
    end

    resources :tutos, only: [:show]

    resources :tutos do
      member do
        put "like", to: "tutos#upvote"
      end
    end

  as :user do
    get     "/register",  to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :register
    get     "/login",     to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get     "/logout",    to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
    get     "/account",   to: "users#show", as: :account
    get     "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
    post    "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
    delete  "/logout" ,   to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
  end

    devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :omniauth_callbacks]

    resources :users

    root "home#landing"
  end
  get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the omniauth callbacks routes with this line

`devise_for :users, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}`

You are overwriting your devise_for :users routes with this line.

`devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :omniauth_callbacks]`

Removing the callback routes.

In your terminal run `rake:routes` To see a full list of routes for your application.

Comment: there is a conflict with the I18n... 
I deleted all I will redo the auth in a while